# JQuery: Appending new cells to table and loop through them works in FF, Chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jsp, foreach

i have some trouble in the following case:

My goal is to append min. 2 Input fields into a table. In the next step it should be able to loop through the new generated cells to get the values from the new generated fields.

The code looks like:

**Call to add new Section (1. input field)**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addAbschnittElement();">
<spring:message code="newSection"/></a>
```

**JS: append new Fields**

```
function addAbschnittElement() {
var ni = document.getElementById('tbl_produktinfo');
var numi = document.getElementById('val');
var num = (document.getElementById('val').value -1)+ 2;
numi.value = num;

var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
var newTrIdName = 'tr_abschnitt_'+num;
var newTdIdName = 'td_abschnitt_'+num;
var newDivIdName = 'div_abschnitt_'+num;
var hiddenValueName = 'hv_'+newTrIdName;
newTr.setAttribute('id',newTrIdName);
newTr.innerHTML = '<td id="' + newTdIdName + '"><div id="'+newDivIdName+'"><input        id="a'+num+'z0" style="width:500px;" ></input><a href=\'#\' onclick=\'removeAbschnitt("' +newTdIdName + '","'+newDivIdName+'")\'>Abschnitt löschen</a> <input type="hidden" value="0" id="'+ hiddenValueName +'" /></div></td>';
ni.appendChild(newTr);

var li = document.getElementById('div_abschnitt_'+num);
var linediv = document.createElement("div");
var lineDivIdName = 'div_line_'+num;
linediv.setAttribute('id',lineDivIdName);
linediv.innerHTML = '<input id="a'+num+'z1" style="width:350px;"></input> <a href=\'#\' onclick=\'addZeile("'+num+'","'+lineDivIdName+'","'+hiddenValueName+'")\'>Zeile hinzufügen</a><br>';
li.appendChild(linediv); 

}
```

**And finally, this function will be called:**

```
function submitForm() {
var mapArray = [];
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

var infoCells = $('#tbl_produktinfo').find('tr').find('td');

infoCells.each(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).children().each(function()
        {
            $(this).children().each(function(){
                if (this.localName == "input" && this.type == "text")
                {
                    mapArray.push(this.id + ";" + $(this).val());
                }
                if (this.localName == "div") {
                    $(this).children().each(function()
                    {
                        if (this.localName == "input" && this.type == "text") {
                            mapArray.push(this.id + ";" + $(this).val());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

// In this place an AJAX call will transfer mapArray to Server
}

The line

```
var infoCells = $('#tbl_produktinfo').find('tr').find('td');
```

returns an empty Object! Therefore the mayarray will never filled with some input...

Where is my mistake?

Additional Info:
The Firebug in FF show me, that the DOM was updatet after adding some Sections! But not in IE :( This could be the Bug, but i´m not sure!

Comment: One of the benefits of jQuery is that it takes away browser inconsistencies, but you're hardly using it. Why?

Comment: @adam thanks you for your suggestion. Could you tell me, where can i improve it?

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: @KamaSeki everything - selectors, attributes, attaching events, dom manipulation - it can all be done in jQuery much more cleanly.

Comment: @adam Thanks adam. I will memorize it for the next challange :) steveukx show me the easy way, how to select only the input filds. That was very smart and help me to solve me problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer, in this case, is preventing the invalid nesting of a `<tr>` element directly within a `<table>` element. In order to append the tr, you would need to be appending it to a `<tbody>` or `<thead>`. As an example:

```
var ni = document.getElementById('tbl_produktinfo');
var tbody = ni.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

if(!tbody) {
  tbody = ni.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
}

// rest of your code

tbody.appendChild(newTr);
```

As you have jQuery available, you can use if for your DOM manipulation too, and switch the append line to:

```
$(ni).append(newTr);
```

jQuery will automatically do the `tbody` wrapping where necessary.

The `submitForm` can also be greatly simplified by using a CSS selector to pick out the input fields in your table:

```
$('#tbl_produktinfo input[type=text]').each(function() {
   mapArray.push(this.id + ';' + this.value);
});
```

Comment: I´ve change the function addAbschnittElement() with your suggestion, but it still not working with IE. When i control the html after put new section into the table, its look like **<table id="tbl_produktinfo"></table>**.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/jHDzK/1/ for a working example (tested down to IE7)

Comment: Thanks steveukx, it was a good hit :) Its still not working but "infoCells" contains the new added Elements.

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer that should help out - if that doesn't sort it, what kind of "not working" are you getting?

Comment: The length of $('#tbl_produktinfo input[type=text]') is 0. Therefore the loop didnt add any Elements in the array.

Comment: thank you :) Ive solved it! Your suggestions point me the right way!